The definite configuration for site-to-site OpenVPN
I have an OpenVPN server reachable via public IPv6 address and an OpenVPN client on a different machine.
The OpenVPN server (10.8.0.1) machine is on the 192.168.1.0/24 network and has the IP address 192.168.1.42.
The OpenVPN client (10.8.0.2) machine is on the 192.168.178.0/24 network and has the IP address 192.168.178.3.
The VPN connection from client to server is established, access (i.e. ping) is working in both directions.
server $ ping 10.8.0.2      # works
server $ ping 192.168.178.3 # works
server $ ping 192.168.178.1 # works now, gateway route was missing (see below)

client $ ping 10.8.0.1      # works
client $ ping 192.168.1.42  # works
client $ ping 192.168.1.1   # does not work

Now I want all participants in the two machine's networks to be able to communicate with each other, aka. a site-to-site VPN.
Yes, there are loads of guides and HowTos out there. To be fair, while most agree on many points, there are subtle differences. I just can't get it right and I feel like I'm about to go nuts. I feel like there is a need for the definitive guide on how to do this.
Questions

In this scenario, what are the absolute necessary steps to get a IPv4 ping from (1) the server to e.g. 192.168.178.1 and (2) any other device in the server network to e.g. 192.168.178.1 working?
How can I further debug this setting?

Site-to-site relevant configuration
Here's what I did so far:

created static IPv4 routes in both the machine's default gateways (routers) to route each others networks to the respective OpenVPN participant machine (e.g. in 192.168.178.1: 192.168.1.0/24 is routed to 192.168.178.3)

enabled IPv4 forwarding via sysctl in both machines

enabled IPv4 TUN forwarding via iptables in both machines

edited the server.conf to contain routes for each other's networks (duplicate-cn is disabled)
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0"
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/server/ccd
route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0


created the additional client-config in the ccd folder with
iroute 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0


used traceroute from OpenVPN server to host in the client's network, shows that packages seem to be routed to the OpenVPN client:
server $ traceroute 192.168.178.1
traceroute to 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2)  48.144 ms  48.749 ms  48.025 ms
2  * * *
...

looks like what I would've personally expected - until hop 1 at least

used traceroute from a host in the OpenVPN server's network to the OpenVPN client, shows that packages seem to be routed to the server machine:
192.168.1.x $ traceroute 192.168.178.3
traceroute to 192.168.178.3 (192.168.178.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  fritz.box (192.168.1.1)
2  openvpn-server.fritz.box (192.168.1.42)
3  * * *
...



Edit 1+3: routes (updated for completeness)
Here are the routes of both the client and the server machine when OpenVPN is connected:
client (192.168.178.3) $ ip route
default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.3 metric 202 mtu 1500 
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.31 metric 303 mtu 1500 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2 
192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.3 metric 202 mtu 1500 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.31 metric 303 mtu 1500

server (192.168.1.42) $ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.42 metric 100 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-b7e09c6559c0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-8a3381fbd26d proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-3593759d1729 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-0038bb1050f6 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-b070c7470a6e proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-da9f81825f78 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.42 metric 100 
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.42 metric 100 
192.168.1.42 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp scope host src 192.168.1.42 metric 100 
192.168.178.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0

machine-in-server-network (192.168.1.23) $ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.23 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-2f4207d39501 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-61e5c9f67d23 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.23 metric 600

The static routing entries of its gateway seem to be missing at this server network participant.
Edit 2: Gateway routes
Here are the routes in the gateways of both machines:
# client gateway (192.168.178.1)
192.168.1.0/24 192.168.178.3
10.8.0.0/24 192.168.178.3

# server gateway (192.168.1.1)
192.168.178.0/24 192.168.1.42
10.8.0.0/24 192.168.1.42

Edit 3: Analyze the package dropping with Wireshark
With those routes in place, I feel like everything should be working now - but it's not.
To further analyze the situation, I captured all ICMP traffic with Wireshark.
At first a ping from server (192.168.1.42) to a device (192.168.1.23) in the server network, which was (known to be) successful:
(192.168.1.42) $ ping 192.168.1.23
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
# Wireshark captured for icmp:
480 52.045068618    192.168.1.42    192.168.1.23    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) request  id=0x003c, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (reply in 483)
483 52.045140522    192.168.1.23    192.168.1.42    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x003c, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (request in 480)

While
(10.8.0.2) $ ping 192.168.1.23
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2109ms
# Wireshark captured for icmp:
534 60.607804242    10.8.0.2    192.168.1.23    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) request  id=0x0038, seq=1/256, ttl=63 (reply in 535)
535 60.607861664    192.168.1.23    10.8.0.2    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0038, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (request in 534)
536 60.612044825    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.23    ICMP    126 Redirect             (Redirect for host)

failed. The redirect appears to be the server gateway suggesting the device to route traffic for 10.8.0.2 directly to 192.168.1.42.
The redirect seems plausible and shows the correct route is in place.
I do wonder, however, why the gateway sends it.
Apparently they won't have any effect for the pinging device is configured with net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0 and drops these redirects. I assume that's an Ubuntu-default to prevent MITMs.
Let's turn this around:
(192.168.1.23) $ ping 10.8.0.2
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.1.42)
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13276ms
# Wireshark captured for icmp:
350 53.535862317    192.168.1.23    10.8.0.2    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) request  id=0xd9c6, seq=1/256, ttl=64 (no response found!)
351 53.543245430    192.168.1.1 192.168.1.23    ICMP    126 Redirect             (Redirect for host)
356 54.537596434    192.168.1.23    10.8.0.2    ICMP    98  Echo (ping) request  id=0xd9c6, seq=2/512, ttl=64 (no response found!)

I get the same results when repeated for the client's non-VPN address 192.168.178.3. Let's trace the route instead.
(192.168.1.23) $ traceroute 10.8.0.2
traceroute to 10.8.0.2 (10.8.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  4.395 ms  6.400 ms  6.378 ms
2  192.168.1.42 (192.168.1.42)  11.252 ms  11.233 ms  11.213 ms
3  * * *
# ... lots of stars
# Wireshark captured for icmp:
1722    212.431270407   192.168.1.1 192.168.1.23    ICMP    102 Time-to-live exceeded (Time to live exceeded in transit)

TTL exceeded in transit suggests that devices along the route would've played ping-pong with the packet until it got old.
Some hints but I'm not much closer to my goal.

What are the routes on 192.168.178.1? Does it have a route to 10.8.0.0/24 and to 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.178.3? Well, it'll help if you show ip route output from all the systems: OpenVPN server, OpenVPN client, the system in the server's network and the target server. And, also it's best to also have routes within OpenVPN server instance, for that connect to its management interface and issue status, when the VPN connection is establihed (for iroute to be executed for it).

Why redacted down? If all you have there is private IPs, don't edit anything down. Addresses in RFC1918 ranges are not a sensitive information (if they are, you have much bigger problem than VPN routing). And it seems it's the case. Just put the raw output of ip route from four systems involved: system behind VPN server, the VPN server, the VPN client and the system behind VPN client. I want to see src hints, default routes, etc., exactly as the system has it, for that I need to reconstruct the behavior of your systems, which is not possible unless the whole routing tables are given.

Thanks for your comment. I was not having static routes for the VPN network in the gateway machines. Now I can ping all machines in each other's network from the server, at least. I added the routes (redacted for brevity) but I already saw that I supposedly cut off important parts so let me do that again.

Well, that's why you usually put the VPN router behind the network gateway, or have a network gateway to be a VPN router. Exactly to not pollute the routing tables on client.

site-to-site VPN This is not an S2S VPN.

@GregAskew well, then what it is? Two remote networks connected by the tunnel — how would you call it?

You pinging 192.168.1.23 from 10.8.0.2. What are routes on 192.168.1.23? Does it have a route towards 10.8.0.2 via 192.168.1.42? // Well, I already said what's wrong. Your VPN endpoints should be either gateways for their networks, or be behind gateways. Don't run it on a sibling system on a network. It's possible to make it work, but it'll be much more hassle.

The problem is not with VPN. Its with your general understanding of routing and networking in general. Imagine VPN is replaced with a physical cable connecting former VPN endpoints; what routes in the network should be? They'll be exactly the same for VPN.

192.168.1.23 does not need the route you want it to have, it's already routing everything to the default gateway which has said routes. Having the routes at 192.168.1.23 would only be a routing optimization, from my understanding.

Above setup is absolutely fine.
I'm not sure what exactly solved the issue but after an unrelated restart of the OpenVPN server's host machine, packages are routed from and to any client of either VPN network to any client of the other.
While this is somewhat disappointing, one key takeaway (thanks to Nikita Kipriyanov) is that both networks' default gateway have to have routes for both the VPN network and the remote LAN through the local VPN participant's host. Another is to turn the metal on and off again.

And you have inefficient routing where routers issue redirects or forward packets back into the same network they came from, and I am not saying "the same Ethernet segment they came from" or "the same interface they were in" — but "the same network", which means, the router merely increased the RTT and hops count without adding any benefits. You arrived at suboptimal, therefore unreasonable solution. It's certainly not "a definite configuration for a site-to-sine VPN" (whatever that could mean).
